# Access Model attribute depending on URL parameter in Django

Tags: django, django-templates

Is it possible to dynamically change a variable name in template?

In the view below I am sending to the template an url parameter called `sl`.

Is it possible to pass that `sl` to the `{{ devize.sl{{sl}} }}` so that it changes dynamically ?

Thank you

```
@login_required
def slList(request,centrudecost,SL):
    queryset = Deviz.objects.filter(centrudecost_id=centrudecost)
    sl = SL    
    print(centrudecost) 
    return render(request, "proiecte/sl_list.html", {"queryset": queryset,"sl":sl})
```

```
{% for devize in queryset %} 
 <td>{{ devize.sl{{sl}} }}</td>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: No, it is not possible to dynamically change a variable name in a Django template in the way you described.

Answer (score 0):

You can not change the template variable dynamically but there is a workaround on the query side. You can create (annotate) a field (my_field) and fill it dynamically in the query:

```
    field = "xyz_fieldname"            # in your case  field = "sl" + SL
    queryset = Deviz.objects.annotate(my_field=F(field)).values('my_field',...).filter(centrudecost_id=centrudecost)
  
    print(centrudecost) 
    return render(request, "proiecte/sl_list.html", {"queryset": queryset})
```

and in the template:

```
{% for devize in queryset %} 
  <td>{{ devize.my_field }} }}</td>

{% endfor %}
```